# Php in phone gap application

Tags: php, cordova, frameworks, phonegap-build

We have to develop an application with more plattform. We would use the framework PhoneGap. For our application we need services of backend, the question is: Does PhoneGap support PHP?

If it doesn't support PHP. In which way we can solve the problem?

The most important thing is: make call server
(Get and Post), parsing a `json` and other functions
that PHP gives.

Answer (score 1):

The backend can be in any language which supports HTTP calls, as PhoneGap is an independent client.

You can use PHP to write an API for use within your Javascript PhoneGap application.

I can recommend the [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) framework to accomplish this.

Comment: Why would you use Lavarel more than another framework to develop on phonegap ? I'm about to start a project and I'm really thinking about using a framework such as Lavarel but I'm not sure which one is better considering I want to use PhoneGap !

Comment: The fact that you are using PhoneGap does not make any difference for the choice of framework. I recommend Laravel because it's easy to get started with and is growing a lot in popularity these days

Answer (score 1):

Phonegap does not have a server. You need to call via Ajax to remote servers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes...you can use PHP or any PHP framework to give backend for mobile app made using phonegap/cordova....point is phonegap/cordova app will be on client mobile which won't understand PHP embedded in phonegap html files....so write an API amd place it on a server and then make AJAX calls to server to do database and other backed operations

Try to return JSON data from the PHP API.....it's a famous data structure and supported by many applications